# jquery: anchor tag is not selected in $(":focusable")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a view as following,

```
<a href="#" onclick="metroUIScript.HomeClick();">
    <div class="back-disable">
    </div>
</a>
```

The anchor here, is getting focus when I do tab. But, its not selected when query the **focus-able** elements using jquery as `$(":focusable")`

In the same view I have some other focus-able elements including another anchor tag as,

`<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>`

All other **focus-able** elements including the later `anchor` element are resulted when I do `$(":focusable")`

What is wrong with the first `anchor` tag?

**EDIT:** When I inspect element, I noticed, *the first anchor tag doesn't have any height but the div inside the anchor does*. Is that making any problem?

**PS:** I am using chrome browser, jQuery version 1.9.1

Comment: Is your anchor visible? Note: the element must be visible in order to be focusable.

Comment: @Satpal - Its getting focus when I do tab.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle / paste your jQuery code here after the selector or check if there are any errors in dev tools.

Comment: check this fiddle its working for me http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/yPVx6/  give some fiddle of your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a blank anchor tag does not work [Jsfiddle - `anchor tag`](http://jsfiddle.net/yPVx6/1/)

```
<a id="test1" href="#" >
   dsadsdsad
</a>

<a id="test2" href="#">dsadsads</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    alert($(":focusable").length);

});
```

Comment: Please add your code to the answer so it can stand by itself if the link to the jsFiddle dies!